# “People have their cars”: In what way are people treated?

Tags: plural-forms

[image]

Picture 1: People are treated **individually**?

Picture 2: People are treated **collectively**.

Picture 3: People are treated **individually**?

To be specific, what’s the difference between “people each have their cars” and “people have his or her car each”? Are both treated individually?

Comment: Maybe you should look at examples of the expression *their own", which would help to eliminate the ambiguity that you describe.

Comment: @JavaLatte Help me…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to talk about people individually, the word **people** isn't a good way to start a sentence. On its own, it means "people in general", and is normally used to make a general statement about people, not about individuals. For example:

> People are taller now than they were a hundred years ago.

If there is a car for every person in a group that has already been mentioned, you would say

> Each person has their own car

"Each person" indicates that you are talking about people individually. **[their](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/their)** is a neat, gender-neutral alternative to "his or her". **[own](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/own)** means "belonging to or done by a particular person or thing".

If there is one car and two or more people, you would say

> They have a car.

**a** indicates that there is just one car: **they have** indicates that they jointly own the car.

Note that, in both sentences, **have** could mean possess, and could also mean that a car is available for their use.

Comment: I want to know the difference between “people each have their cars” and “people have his or her car each.”

Comment: The first might be understandable in a given context, but it is not idiomatic. The second is not grammatical and not even vaguely understandable.

Comment: but “The tickets cost £20 each” is correct

Comment: **each** can be a pronoun "each has a car", a determiner "each person has a car", an adverb "they have a car each". i have added something to my answer to explain why your sentences don't sound natural.

Answer (score 0):

> people have his or her car each

*People* is a plural word so the correct pronoun is *their* ...

> people have their car each

but since *each* is used to talk about distributing to individuals, you can't use it with a plural noun.  So you'll need to change *people* to the singular *person* and use a determiner since it's singular.

> A person has his or her car each.

*Each* works much more gracefully as a determiner, so this is probably the most usual way to express this:

> Each person has his or her car.

---

> People have their car

This is technically saying a group of multiple X's have 1 car.

> People have their cars

This is technically saying a group of multiple X's have more than one car.

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/each  But a dictionary said “The tickets cost £20 each”